# Gravitational wave equations?

Tags: gravitational-waves

I am looking for a set of equations, one to calculate GW amplitude in watts and one to calculate frequency... I believe I have located the correct frequency equation yet I cannot find a source for power??  Any ideas??

To clarify, the equation below I got from Scott Hughes, in my correspondence with him he says:

"Dear Mr Vogeler —

I’m afraid I’ve also lost the correspondence we shared a few years ago.  As I recall, I outlined the power produced by two masses orbiting each other.  It’s not too hard to reconstruct that formula: If the masses are m1 and m2, and they move on a circular trajectory of radius R, and they complete an orbit in a time T, then the amount of power they put out is

P_{gw} = (32/5)(G/c^5) m1^2 m2^2/(m1 + m2)^2 R^4 (2 pi/T)^6

Here, G is Newton’s gravitation constant, and c is the speed of light.

That factor of G/c^5 is a killer: G is a small quantity; c is quite large; c^5 is huge.  The lesson of this formula is that you need m1 and m2 to be large, and the period to be short, in order for the system to produce appreciable waves.  2 pi R/T is the speed that the bodies whirl around each other, and that indeed needs to be a substantial fraction of the speed of light for this work."

When I run these numbers, it appears I do in fact get watts?  Is this really an accurate way to express the GW power?  When I see other amplitude or power numbers given it seems to be a dimensionless unit?  For example I saw that one detector can detect an amplitude of 10^-21, but its doesn't say what unit this number is.  I assume its calculated the same, but I am not sure if its really the same as watts.

What I am doing is imagining I have a particle accellerator that I can place two 1mg masses in and spin up to 299,000 km/s.  My radius I had at 50cm, I ended up with GW=10^-18 m^2 kg/s^3 which is about one attowatt if indeed this calculates watts??  I know that if someone tried to do that the G forces would be insane, but its just a thought experiment.  I wanted to see how much velocity is needed to hit the detectable range.

Comment: The amplitude can't be measured in joules. Typically, the amplitude of gravitational waves is given as a strain (which is unitless as it is the length change relative to the length). Otherwise, it of course it all depends on the source emitting the wave, the distance between source and observer. So it is not clear what you want to know. (Source recommendation: any introduction to general relativity, e.g. L. Ryder: Introduction to General Relativity).

Comment: Have you heard it said that the earth loses 200 watts in GW radiation per orbit??  I am not even sure if that is what standard is used for say Ligo to detect GW.  I am trying to calculate hypothetical what I would need to accelerate say two small masses in rotational velocity to make a measurable GW in a lab environment.  I realize this may not be possible even in 100 years but it's just a thought experiment.  I'm just a freshman astronomy student in community college who bite off more than he can chew for his final essay.... in need of help!!! Lol I hope this explains what I'm up to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power (energy over time) that is radiated away can be approximated with

$$\rm P = \dot E = \frac{d E}{d t} = -\frac{32 G^4 M_1^2 M_2^2 (M_1+M_2)}{5 c^5 r^5}$$

and the rate at which the angular momentum is lost

$$  \rm \dot L = \frac{d L}{d t} = -\frac{32 G^{7/2} M_1^2 M_2^2 \sqrt{M_1+M_2}}{5 c^5 r^{7/2}} $$

The frequency is

$$ \rm f = \sqrt{\frac{G (M_1+M_2)}{\pi r^3}} $$

and the radial relative velocity

$$ \rm \dot r = \frac{d r}{d t} = -\frac{64 G^3 (M_1 M_2) (M_1+M_2)}{5 c^5 r^3} $$

That gives a merging time of

$$ \rm t= \frac{5 c^5 r^4}{256 G^3 (M_1 M_2)(M_1+M_2)} $$

If the merger is so far away that the cosmological redshift z is much larger than 0 you have to multiply the time and divide the frequency by $\rm z+1$. The amplitude would in any case be proportional to $\rm P/f$.

Note that this are only first order approximations where the final ringdown is not accounted for, the whole fullrelativistic story can only be computed in large computer clusters.

Comment: I had a thought experiment, I imagined I could simulate a binary system in a lab.  My idea at first had more to do with EM fields, I imagined two 1 meter diameter spheres filled with mercury just for ease of calculations.  I know the density of mercury is 13.56 g/cm^3 applying some geometry we can approximate a mass of 7300kg, which made me wonder further what if I could take much smaller masses more feasible to accelerate without blowing up the lab, could we in theory produce GW this way lol.  A thought experiment I am trying to write an essay for.  Trying to find equation I can plug mass in.

Comment: That was so I could ask, if we cannot calculate in joules then why have I heard it said the earth loses and equivalant of 200 watts Gravitational energy due to GW or radiation??  Pardon me I am very new and I am having some difficulty in understanding but I am giving it alot of effort.  I am greatful for any thorough explanations like the one above.  Very thankful.

Comment: Why do you have all variables Romanized (`\rm`) instead of normal?

Comment: @AndrewVogeler - the earth does not lose rest mass, but kinetic energy which is also equivalent to mass by e=mc²γ. @ Kyle Kanos: just for better readability.

Comment: @СимонТыран I don't find it easier to read. Or more difficult, for that matter. It's strikingly different from every other textbook, journal article or Q&A in this site that it's very odd to me that it was done.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have mathjax, this is the same format one can use in google calculator isn't it?  Are there any alternative ways that are free I can use to make my equations look like I would write them down?

Comment: https://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got this from Scott Hughes MIT.  This is what I was searching for and I quote:

"....if the masses are m1 and m2, and they move on a circular trajectory of radius R, and they complete an orbit in a time T, then the amount of power they put out is:

P=(32/5)(G/c^5)m1^2m2^2/(m1+m2)^2R^4(2pi/T)^6"

This is very similar to the equation above I see.

I hope I copied that correctly.  I probably didn't explain well what I needed, thank God I got lucky with a final saving email from Mr. Hughes!!  I'm going to make sure I do not lose this email!!!

Thank you all for attempting to help me.  I typically don't answer my own questions but I didn't really this did not come from my brain!!

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematics.  It's the site standard and greatly improves readability.

Comment: Note: It is considered good style on physics.SE to answer your own question if you can do so correctly (because that usually means you learned something and now share that with the community).

Comment: That should be the same formula as above when you rearrange it, you get the power as a funktion of t and r but since t is also a function of r you can also eliminate the t and be left with only r as a variable.

Comment: Yes I noticed that, thanks I wasn't keen enough on my algebra to see when rearranged as per Dr. Hughes showed me we get units in watts!!  What's cooler still...  Dr. River baker found an equation for expressing GW power from a change in momentum or in this thought experiment acceleration.  That's much much higher, ... edit i spoke too soon p=1.76*10^-52(2R(df/dt))^2. Here df=force and dt=time for one revolution.